# Apache Velocity and Escaping # followed by $

Tags: velocity

Question regarding Velocity and I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere online... Maybe it's really that obvious, anyway, the question:

I have a variable called $link and when I want to use it as a hyperlink to an anchor I use e.g.:

```
<a href="#$link">something</a>
```

And I get that as a literal output...

How can I get if $link = "bla":

```
<a href="#bla">something</a>
```

as output?

And also the same problem with:

```
<a href="#$link-something-else">something</a>
```

to get as

```
<a href="#bla-something-else">something</a>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer:

```
<a href="#${link}">something</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#${link}-something-else">something</a>
```